# XCode 5 Storyboard Internal Inconsistencies

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

In XCode 5 DP6 and now GM, I have a problem with all of my projects not allowing me to use an Image Asset in more than one place on a storyboard without getting an error upon launch from XCode stating "The document 'main.storyboard' has X internal inconsistencies that were found and repaired. Please save this document to fix the inconsistencies."

If you choose to list the inconsistencies, you see that it's saying that every UIButton, or UIImageView that uses an image from your asset catalog, past the first use of it, is duplicated in the Storyboard. I try to save the document, but it does nothing, and when I relaunch the project, I get the same error.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it's quite possible to use an Image Asset more than once in a project, right? I do not need to make a duplicate image for each time I want to use it, do I?

Has anyone else run into this problem? It occurs in every project I make, on two separate machines, in both XCode 5DP6, and XCode 5GM.

Comment: I am also having this problem recurrently, in addition all of my freeform UIView has reached the maximum vertically allowed height (which is something around a few thousands), and the only way to fix it was to open the storyboard as xml file and change height manually rather than visually or trough IB. I didn't find a way to remove the error, but seems that the app runs fine.

Comment: This is really weird and annoying

Answer (score 2):

same bug here. you should file a bug report (https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

For me it's seem like it's the message is also incorrect.
If I check the diff before and after this error I have this:

```
-  <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="310"/>
+  <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="319.99999999999994" height="310"/>
```

Comment: I filed a bug, and it was marked as a dupe. Apple is at least aware of the problem, and we'll see if they can manage to fix it in the final release.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same results using the GM. In my case I have saved a copy of the storyboard file before and after the "repair." The diff indicates that the files are binary equals.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a BarItemImage. In the details it said that the problem originated in the Image "law.png".

Once I renamed the Image (in Finder), imported it new and reassigned it to the TabBar, the problem was gone.