# Multiple UIImageViews with same image gives Inconsistency error

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xcode5, internal

I add 3 UIImageView objects to a MainViewController.
For each of them add the same image "test.png".
The images display correctly for each of the controls.
Close the MainViewController and reopen it.

You get an error displayed saying "The MainViewControllre" has 3 internal inconsistencies that were found and repaired.

The details for the message indicates that there are resources with the same name.

Although the images still display correctly and the program executes in the simulator I would like to solve this message.

This seems to be something that was introduced in XCode 5.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be using StoryBoards for setting these images?  I remember hearing about this issue a few months ago.  Check out this SO post:

[Storyboard Internal Inconsistencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967190/storyboard-internal-inconsistencies)

Seems like it may have been a bug in an early release of Xcode 5.  The correctly marked answer here states updating to Mavericks and Xcode 5.0.1 fixed the issue.  Also, if this in fact the problem, and you can not update for what ever reason, removing the storyboard references to the images and adding the image to the image view programmatically may solve your issue.  Trivial example, but just in case you (or anyone else reading this) doesn't know:

[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"]];

Comment: It happens with or without storeboards.  Leaving the image bank in the Interface builder (no image) and adding it programmatically solves the problem, but adds program complexity in other areas.